# Android: How to create an unrestricted background service, beyond APK permissions?

Tags: android

I'd like to create a Java/Kotlin background service that is not afflicted by resource management limitations at all.

I know that this is pretty much contradicting Android design principles, and I am pretty sure this is not possible for a normal app.

But having full root permissions, what would be the cleanest way to build/install such a service? I would still like to use Android Studio to develop, and benefit from Java API portability.

**Edit:** It turned out that my question has been misleading. I am not targetting an existing Android HW Device, where a user has to grant permissions, but rather a custom AOSP installation, which i have full control of. I already figured out that I probably have to write a system service for this. However, I will accept the given answer for the general case as reference for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [this approach](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#support_for_other_use_cases) and ask your user to add your application to the white list. Any app that is there won't be a subject of system resource management regarding the Doze mode; thus, the system won't kill your service while it's in background while you don't break the other limitations such as max amount of available memory.

Or you can just show an alert and ask the user to add your application to the white list manually.

Comment: "Any app that is there won't be a subject of system resource management" -- that only affects Doze mode. There are plenty of other forms of system resource management (heap limits, out of memory killer, etc.).

Comment: Sure, but I thought the author was asking exactly for this type of resource management. I don't think that he's going to prevent the system from killing his app in case if it's exceeded the limits of heap dedicated to the process.

Comment: I interpreted "not afflicted by resource management limitations *at all*" (emphasis added) to cover more than Doze mode. But, the question is unclear on what "resource management limitations" are of interest. I just did not want people to think that the battery optimization whitelist covers all resource management.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare for the remark, I've updated the answer